# ERROR on PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in hash function

Tags: php, arrays, string, constructor, blockchain

I want to build blockchain using PHP-OOP.

my code:

```
    class Block {

        public function __construct($timestamp, $transactions, $previousHash = null) {
            $this->previousHash = $previousHash;
            $this->timestamp = $timestamp;
            $this->transactions = $transactions;
            $this->nonce = 0;
            $this->hash = $this->calculateHash();
            $this->difficulty = 2;
        }

        /** Returns the SHA256 of this block (by processing all the data stored inside this block)*/
        public function calculateHash() {
            return hash("sha256", $this->previousHash.$this->timestamp.((string)$this->transactions).$this->nonce);
        }
      }
```

It shows me this error:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/istabraq/bctest/test2/a2.php on line 14
```

any idea please?

Comment: `(string)$this->transactions` isn't going to do what you you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That transform array to string you can use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
        public function calculateHash() {
            return hash("sha256", $this->previousHash.$this->timestamp.(implode('', $this->transactions)).$this->nonce);
        }
```